# Как узнать максимальный объём передаваемых данных в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой записи данных в базу MySQL. Одним запросом пытался записать порядка 50к строк, получил по башке от сервера - говорит, что превышен максимальный объём данных.

Друзья, как мне узнать этот максимальный допустимый размер передаваемых данных от приложения к серверу?

Comment: а вы через GET данные передавали или через POST? была такая проблема на сервере, ограничение на передачу через GET, а через POST всё нормально записывается, может это и ваш случай. Это если доступа к настройки сервера нет, а если есть, то можно и для GET расширить объёмы

Comment: Первое правило работы с большими данными: работать итерациями, подгружать и загружать небольшими частями. Разница между 50 000 и 500 раз по 100 будет, но из-за скорости добавления данных в БД не будет принципиальной. Верхний порог все равно никак не определить, кроме как экспериментально, он будет зависеть от кода и окружения.

Comment: @MasterAlex нет, не POST и не GET. Формирую запрос парсером XML файла из php. Файл большой, запрос, соответственно, тоже... 
@Etki спасибо, уже так пробовал - всё работает, только вот пришлось время выполнения скрипта увеличить =/
Кстати, думал сделать такой вариант: записать данные из XML в файл sql или простой txt, а в БД загружать уже не из PHP, а из этого файла. Что скажете?

Comment: @lommusic вряд ли будет ощутимая разница, можно делать, как удобней. В файл тоже лучше писать построчно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно не хватило памяти для insert.

Почитай "Как MySQL работает с памятью" на http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=034

Comment: о, сенкс, утром почитаю отпишусь

Comment: Мда... Учиться учиться и ещё раз учиться... Благодарю!